# Assign cURL response to variable without showing it on the command line bash

Tags: bash, http, curl

I am currently making a bash script where I would like to make a cURL request and assign its response to a variable. This part is easy, but is there a way to do it without the response also being printed out on the command line?

Here's what I have right now:

```
session_curl="$(pbpaste)"

{do some other stuff here}

tmp=$(mktemp)
echo "$session_curl" > "$tmp"
chmod +x "$tmp"
"$tmp"
rm "$tmp"
```

Comment: When using e.g. `foo=$(curl ifconfig.me)` on sh, bash and zsh there will be no response printed to stdout. Instead the progess will be printed. You could use `curl -s` or `curl --silent`: `-s, --silent
              Silent or quiet mode. Do not show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl mute.`

Comment: If the actual goal is to write it to a file, `curl` can do that directly with `curl -o "$tmp" https://example.com/whatever` (or with a shell redirect, like `curl https://example.com/whatever >"$tmp"`)

Comment: share us your curl command. Using $(curl foo.com --silent ) it works